# Circle transparent text

Tags: css, text, transparent

Hey guys I am trying to make this number in the circle transparent, I tried with

```
color: #000; 
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
```

but the number is black i tried with opicity, but it works for the whole div.
This is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/ivailo/3q6ej7cc/6/

```
BODY {
background-color: tan;
}
span.green {
background: #5EA226;
border-radius: 0.8em;
-moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
-webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
color: #ffffff;
display: inline-block;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 1.6em;
margin-right: 15px;
text-align: center;
width: 1.6em; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to change the transparency value which can be from 0 to 1

```
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3q6ej7cc/7/

Comment: Yes I know with transparent I mean I want to see the background.

Answer (score 1):

After your comment on this answer, it appears you are trying to make the background under the text show through. Unfortunately, the CSS property that allows this, [`background-clip:text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip), isn't well supported yet, and doesn't work in IE or Firefox:

> The background is painted within (clipped to) the foreground text; this is currently only supported with a -webkit- prefixed background-clip property.

For now, the simplest method is to just use an image.

However, if you would rather not use a static image(Like a `jpg` or `png`), you might be able to [use an SVG](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/02/16/create-animated-text-fills/).

### Older answer

The [`rgba` functional notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgba) uses a number between `1` and `0` to set the `alpha` channel(rgb**Alpha**) , with 1 having no transparency.

So, your `color:rgba(0,0,0,1)` is just black.

Set the color to `rgba(0,0,0,0.5)`, or another decimal between `1` and `0`:

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zq9037gk/)

Comment: Yes I know with transparent I mean I want to see the background.

Comment: You want to see the tan color behind it? Why can't you just set the color to tan? https://jsfiddle.net/zqsLjrzd/

Comment: Its not for this background for another which is not just color

Comment: @ivailo Then you can't really do it, I would recommend using an image